# Количество дней между двумя датами, без учета выходных и праздничных дней

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

столкнулся с такой задачкой

Есть перечень этапов с датой начала и окончания этапа. Необходимо вычислить количество дней между этими двумя датами, при этом исключить из расчета выходные и праздничные дни

Даты начала и окончания этапов содержатся в excel файле (Stages.xlsx): датасет **stages_data**

Даты выходных и праздничных дней, содержатся в отдельном excel файле (Holidays.xlsx) и представлены в датасете **holidays_data**

Для решения задачи использовал функцию **np.busday_count**, с параметром **holidays**, который принимает значения из датафрейма **holidays_data**

Но на выходе получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке :

> ValueError: Cannot safely convert provided holidays input into an
> array of dates

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема ?
Поля всех дат, которые используются для расчета, соответствуют типу данных datetime64[ns]

Примеры файлов :

https://disk.yandex.com/i/DlVyCaELXT7NJw (Holidays.xlsx - список дат выходных и праздников)

https://disk.yandex.com/i/7w3PDaXtue_mGQ (Stages.xlsx - даты этапов)

Код :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#читаем данные из файлов
stages_data = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Stages.xlsx'
holidays_data = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Holidays.xlsx'

#создаем датафреймы
df_stages = pd.read_excel(stages_data, sheet_name='data')
df_holidays = pd.read_excel(holidays_data, sheet_name='data')

#устанавливаем формат Дата для всех столбцов
df_stages['Начало'] = pd.to_datetime(df_stages['Начало'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
df_stages['Окончание'] = pd.to_datetime(df_stages['Окончание'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
df_holidays['Дата'] = pd.to_datetime(df_holidays['Дата'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

#вычисляем кол-во дней между двумя датами (исключая праздники и выходные)
days = np.busday_count(df_stages['Начало'], df_stages['Окончание'],holidays=[df_holidays])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: также пробовал конвертировать список дат с выходными и праздничными днями в список : df_holidays_2=df_holidays['Дата'].tolist(), в результате ошибка также повторяется

Comment: Приведите полностью стек-трейс ошибки, чтобы было понятно хотя бы в какой строке она произошла, какое место кода её вызвало.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\holidays.py", line 21, in <module>
    days = np.busday_count(df_stages['Начало'], df_stages['Окончание'],holidays=[df_holidays_2])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in busday_count
ValueError: Cannot safely convert provided holidays input into an array of dates (также добавил скрин с окном кода и номером строк, в текст вопроса)

Comment: А зачем у вас там квадратные скобки? Мне кажется они лишние. Попробуйте `holidays=df_holidays_2`

Comment: попробовал, результат не изменился, ошибка также появляется : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\holidays.py", line 21, in <module>
    days = np.busday_count(df_stages['Начало'], df_stages['Окончание'],holidays=df_holidays_2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in busday_count
ValueError: Cannot safely convert provided holidays input into an array of dates

Comment: Вы уверены, что применяете верный формат преобразования даты? Судя по файлам xslx, у вас первым значением идёт месяц. ну и разделители проверьте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо привести значения datetime к единому формату, поскольку np.busday_count() требует datetime типа `datetime64[D]`, а pandas хранит в `datetime64`:

```
days = np.busday_count(np.array(df_stages['Начало'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')),
                                np.array(df_stages['Окончание'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')),
                                         holidays=df_holidays["Дата"].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

days:

```
array([33, 59,  2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: точно ! заработало. Спасибо большое